# When were the seeds of this Maximum Ride Forever plot element sown?

Tags: young-adult, hybrid, maximum-ride

I haven't read Maximum Ride in a few years. I recall I stopped somewhere in the middle of Angel. I found out that in the last book

> MAX IS PREGNANT WITH FANG'S KID!!! (She's a minor, right?!?!!)

1. When exactly did that begin, i.e.? (book/chapter) How exactly did that come to begin?

> Did they have sex? Or was it some artificial insemination or whatever? When did the natural or artificial insemination happen?

2. Also, how old is Max at

> the conception of her child

?

Comment: From what my wife tells me, it's an *egg*, so you can tell that the biology is different in that regard.

Comment: @CreationEdge ummmm cloaca? I don't think she's that much of a bird...is she?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Edit please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, the child was conceived naturally in this scene in Chapter 18 of *Maximum Ride Forever*:

> Fang sighed. “Maximum Ride, you’re the most stubborn person I’ve ever met, and sometimes it seems like your sole purpose in life is to make mine harder, but I swear, I love you more than I thought I could love anyone or anything.”
>
> “Then stay,” I whispered, clenching my eyes shut just as they started to well up.
>
> I felt Fang’s hands on the sides of my face, his thumbs wiping away my tears. I felt the heat coming off his body, heard the catch of his breath. And when our lips finally came together, our kisses were urgent, our bodies hungry. As he moved his hands through my tangled hair, I looked up at him. Inhaled. And said, “Yes.”
>
> **We sank to the ground, the dried leaves crinkling under us, and time fell away for a while.**
>
> I couldn’t tell if our voices rose in pleasure or pain, couldn’t tell if my heart was breaking or bursting open with joy. I only knew I didn’t want to pull away from him for a single second, and it was only when we both gasped for a breath that I realized Fang’s eyes were squeezed shut and his lashes were wet.

Then, towards the end of the novel it's mentioned that the child, [Phoenix](http://maximumride.wikia.com/wiki/Phoenix), is born. Although the birth is discussed in a past-tense manner

> It wasn’t all bad, though. In the room I shared with Fang, I swore through a much-too-long childbirth and may have punched Fang and ripped a pillow in half, but I ended up with a wrinkled, utterly perfect nugget of joy as a souvenir.

We see that it was a live, natural birth, and did not involve an egg, despite my presumption and Max's fears:

> I patted my belly button, feeling the swell that was growing a tiny bit bigger every day. I pressed my knuckles against the small curve, kneading in, but it always rebounded.
>
> I really hoped this wasn’t going to be a great big egg to lay. How could I possibly sit still on it for nine months?

As far as their ages go, the last bit of information I can find is than in the book *Fang*, Max turns 15. Fang is 6 months younger than she is. I can't find information about how long after each novel then next one takes place, but I believe they're generally immediately following. Max was 14 in the first novel, and it took until the 6th for her to have a birthday.

While it may be one's assumption that the two characters were underage, you must remember that they are not *human*, as they're human-avian hybrids, among other things, and that by this time the apocalypse had struck, during the conclusion of *Nevermore*, so there wasn't even a legal system to classify "underage".

Comment: I didn't know there was an apocalypse. Whoa. Well thanks CreationEdge/your wife ^-^

Comment: @BCLC Glad I could help. I only looked it up because my wife has read the whole series except the last (since the last 2 before it were apparently even more terrible than Patterson's normal YA material)

Comment: Guess its a good thing I didn't finish Angel (or continue after Fang). Wait what do you mean looked it up? Where?

Comment: @BCLC I got the ebook and scanned through it, and then referenced stuff on the previous books, which matched what my wife told me. We have the hard copies of the other 8 on the shelf beside me.

Comment: how exactly did you know where to look?

Comment: @BCLC In the new book? I searched for egg, baby, Fang, and love, trying to spot passages relevant to the event.

Comment: 'love'. Nice keyword idea.

Comment: Yup. I knew a YA novel would beat around the bush about it. I also looked for signs that the baby was artificial, using Fang's DNA, which is featured in the book, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read *Hawk* and *City of the Dead* to really understand what age she was. They follow Max and Fang's daughter, Phoenix, who has changed her name to Hawk. I love this series with my whole heart, but was a little surprised by the whole pregnant thing.

In *Hawk*, Max says that her daughter is a few years younger than she was when she had her, and Hawk is 15. I assume that Max was 16 or 17 when Hawk was born, but probably 16 when she was conceived.

The flock celebrated their birthday during FANG, but then they went to Antarctica and Africa to help the people there. The apocalypse happened around a year later, wiping out most humans who weren't underground.

Comment: thanks fangsblog. are hawk and city of the dead like...a spin-off of maximum ride?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when Phoenix was born Max was around 15 as the only birthday that happened throughout the entire series was in Fang (max's 15th) so at the most she was 15 or 16 when she had her baby. I'm 7 yrs too l8 istg/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't vandalize posts, not even your own.  If you don't want to keep it you should simply delete it.  Late posts aren't a problem, but the more evidence they provide the better they will be received.